# Event Listener does not work if I change outerHTML

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, queryselector, outerhtml

I have 3 images in html.
I select the images with `querySelectorAll`, turn them into an array, and:

**Step1**
I enclose them inside a `<div>` tag, adding an `.img-container` class, using `outerHTML`.

**Step2**
I add an Event Listener to the images.
When the images are clicked, I console log "img has been clicked".

If I run Step1 alone, the code works.
If I run Step2 alone, the code works.

When I try to run both Step1 and Step2, the Event Listener (Step 2) does not work.

Any help?

```js
// Select all img tags
const allImg = document.querySelectorAll('img');


// ***STEP 1 ***
//Enclose imgs in divs (and add img-container class)
const allImgArr = Array.from(allImg).map((curr) =>
  curr.outerHTML = '<div class="img-container">' + curr.outerHTML + '</div>' );

// ***STEP 2***
//Click on image to console.log 'img has been clicked'
const allImgArrTwo = Array.from(allImg).map((curr) =>
  curr.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log ('img has been clicked')
    }));
```

```css
.img-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p>Img 1</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/574071/pexels-photo-574071.jpeg" width="100" height="100" alt="">


<p>Img 2</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181676/pexels-photo-1181676.jpeg" width="100" height="100"  alt="">

<p>Img 3</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181244/pexels-photo-1181244.jpeg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
```

Comment: since you change the images outerHTML, the `allImg` array no longer contains the img elements you started with

Comment: Many thx @JaromandaX 
How can I make it work?

Comment: get the list of images after you clobber them

Comment: what's with all the `Array.from(allImg).map()`? why not a simple `allImg.forEach()`? the values you return from these `.map()` functions are useless anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to add event listeners to every image. Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) should solve your problem. That makes the second step superfluous. The snippet demonstrates event delegation and a way to create elements without the need for `outerHTML`.

Fork this [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ewmw31?file=script.js) to play with this code.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, evt => {
  if (evt.target.nodeName === `IMG`) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`image has been clicked`);
  }
});

// No steps needed.
// Alternative for creating div.img-container for each image
// (avoids outerHTML).
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach( img => 
  img.insertAdjacentElement( `beforebegin`, 
    Object.assign(document.createElement(`div`), {className: `img-container`}) )
  .appendChild(img)
);
```

```css
.img-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p>Img 1</p>
<img src="//images.pexels.com/photos/574071/pexels-photo-574071.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-lukas-574071.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">


<p>Img 2</p>
<img src="//images.pexels.com/photos/1181676/pexels-photo-1181676.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-christina-morillo-1181676.jpg" width="100" height="100"  alt="">

<p>Img 3</p>
<img src="//images.pexels.com/photos/1181244/pexels-photo-1181244.jpeg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
```

Comment: Tried it with [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), and seems to also work well.

`document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if (e.target.matches('img') ) {
console.log ('img has been clicked!');
}
});`

Comment: That's js for you ;): most of the time there are different ways to get to the same result. The linked stackblitz project uses a className for the image and `evt.target.closest('.img')`

Answer (score 4):

Changing `outerHTML` is not the best way to work with HTML elements. Create a new `<div>`, set `.className` to `"img-container"` and add the image inside the `<div>`.

Full demo:

```js
// Select all img tags
const allImg = document.querySelectorAll('img');


// ***STEP 1 ***
//Enclose imgs in divs (and add img-container class)
const allImgArr = Array.from(allImg).map((curr) => {
  const parent = document.createElement("div");
  parent.className = "img-container";
  curr.replaceWith(parent);
  parent.appendChild(curr);
  return parent;
});

// ***STEP 2***
//Click on image to console.log 'img has been clicked'
const allImgArrTwo = Array.from(allImg /* change 'allImg' to 'allImgArr' if you want to log when the <div> AND the <img> are clicked */).map((curr) =>
  curr.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('img has been clicked');
  }));
```

```css
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p>Img 1</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/574071/pexels-photo-574071.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-lukas-574071.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">


<p>Img 2</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181676/pexels-photo-1181676.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-christina-morillo-1181676.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">

<p>Img 3</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181244/pexels-photo-1181244.jpeg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
```

**Edit on Mon Aug 22 2022 11:16:16 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)**: Replaced `replaceChild` with `replaceWith` (based on comment)

Comment: check out [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Select all img tags
const allImg = document.querySelectorAll('img');

//Enclose imgs in divs (and add img-container class)
const allImgArr = Array.from(allImg).map((curr) =>
  curr.outerHTML = '<div class="img-container">' + curr.outerHTML + '</div>' );
const allImg1 = document.querySelectorAll('img');
//Click on image to console.log 'img has been clicked'
const allImgArrTwo = Array.from(allImg1).map((curr) =>
  curr.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log ('img has been clicked')
    }));
```

```css
.img-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p>Img 1</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/574071/pexels-photo-574071.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-lukas-574071.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">


<p>Img 2</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181676/pexels-photo-1181676.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-christina-morillo-1181676.jpg" width="100" height="100"  alt="">

<p>Img 3</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181244/pexels-photo-1181244.jpeg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
```

From What I get the Problem is you are replacing the outer html so the allImg isn't representing those images anymore, so you could fix it by selecting allimgs again and then adding the even listener.